# Salesforce data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have created two import definitions to import reports and object info from the Sales cloud.
but I am not able to see those data extensions in the Salesforce data extension folder. they are appearing in the normal data extension folder.
what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

While creating Import definitions using 'Salesforce Objects and Reports', the DE is always created under the DE folder of that specific business unit and not the shared DE. This is the expected behavior. After the DE is created, you have the option to move them to the shared DE folder (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Please create a support case with Salesforce on why by default imported salesforce reports are created in data extensions in your case. However, you can still move them back to Salesforce data extensions folder, if you plan to on send tracking data back using guided sends.